# Unit Testing Google OAuth2 with PHP

Tags: php, unit-testing, google-api

I'm wondering if there is some way to do unit testing using the Google API for authentication using the Google API PHP Client.

Here is the kind of code example that I want to use around my unit testing case.
(but i want to do more complicated things around it of course that is why i need to do unit testing)

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/userinfo/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is messy, but possible. It is not going to be exactly unit testing, but still...

You need to

- either write stubs for the parts of your code which do actual
  requests to the google api, which would return predefined responses
  which your code needs to be ready for.
- or create a simple separate
  service in your local network which would behave like google api web
  service. It is easier than it sounds - a simple php script with a
  switch and a readfile(responseFileNumberN)...

Either way you need to decide which of google's behaviours/errors you need to emulate. Testing on live service is a bad idea. This way you are going to test google's api which is out of your control or your network connection, not your app.

Comment: Thanks kgb, i'm gonna give a try to this :)